# Could this string be split properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, split

I'm using Rails, and have this seed data:

```
majors = 'business/marketing: 15%|social sciences: 14%|health professions: 11%|english: 10%|engineering: 9%|psychology: 8%|biology: 7%|history: 5%'
```

In my view files, I have access to `@college.majors`, and then I split it on `|`, and print it out. However, I'm trying to make it into a bar graph now using [Google Charts](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart). It needs to be formatted like this:

```
var popular_majors = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Major', 'Percentage'],
          ['Psychology',  20],
          ['Business',  15],
          ['Engineering',  12],
          ['Biology',  11],
          ['Economics',  8],
          ['History',  6],
          ['Mathematics',  5]
        ]);
```

Is it possible for the to split the string properly, and then iterate through it in such a way where I could print out the odd members as the majors, and the even members as the percentages?

code:

```
var popular_majors = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<%= @college.majors.gsub('%', '').split('|').map{ |element| element.split(': ') }.unshift(['Major', 'Percentage']).to_s.html_safe %>)
            var popular_majors_options = {
              title: 'Most Popular Majors',
              legend: 'none',
              hAxis: {title: 'Percentage'}
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('popular_majors_chart'));
            chart.draw(popular_majors, popular_majors_options);

            var ethnicities = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<%= @college.ethnicity.gsub('%', '').split('|').map{ |element| element.split(': ') }.unshift(['Ethnicity', 'Percentage']).to_s.html_safe %>)
            var ethnicities_options = {
              title: 'Ethnicities',
              legend: 'none',
              hAxis: {title: 'Percentage'}
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('ethnicities_chart'));
            chart.draw(ethnicities, ethnicities_options);
```

Comment: Yes, that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
content = "business/marketing: 15%|social sciences: 14%|health professions: 11%|english: 10%|engineering: 9%|psychology: 8%|biology: 7%|history: 5%"
content.split('|').map{ |element| result = element.split(': '); [result[0], result[1].to_i] }.unshift(['Major', 'Percentage'])
# => [["Major", "Percentage"], ["business/marketing", 15], ["social sciences", 14], ["health professions", 11], ["english", 10], ["engineering", 9], ["psychology", 8], ["biology", 7], ["history", 5]]
```

I missed the point of having it in JavaScript in your view. You can do that by simply calling `to_s` on the resulting array:

```
var popular_majors = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<%= @college.majors.split('|').map{ |element| result = element.split(': '); [result[0], result[1].to_i] }.unshift(['Major', 'Percentage']).to_s.html_safe %>)
```

Comment: The "content" is actually `@college.majors`, which is equal to `business/marketing: 15%|social sciences: 14%|health professions: 11%|english: 10%|engineering: 9%|psychology: 8%|biology: 7%|history: 5%`. Does that change anything?

Comment: @AdamZerner, then it's even easier. See updated answer. Have a look at [`Array#map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-map) and [`Array#unshift`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-unshift) if you want to understand what's going on.

Comment: @AdamZerner: updated answer to show an example of how to use this in your view with Google Charts.

Comment: Is it possible to have the percents be integers? Like 15 instead of "15%"?

Comment: @AdamZerner, you can also use `to_i` on the second element of the splitted array, like I show in my updated answer.

Comment: I just tried that and something went wrong (tried it for ethnicities to). I edited my question with code. See this web page: http://www.collegeanswerz.com/university-of-pittsburgh/academics/professors/do-professors-explain-things-clearly-are-professors-interesting. Do you know what I could do to fix it?

Comment: I think you have to use `.html_safe` after `.to_s`, or else the string will get escaped. @AdamZerner

Comment: That almost, worked, it just says `Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string` (See http://www.collegeanswerz.com/university-of-pittsburgh/academics/professors/do-professors-explain-things-clearly-are-professors-interesting). Do you know what that's referring to?

Comment: It's still a string. To fix it see my earlier update. (My current answer should work)

Comment: Sorry, I'm still getting the error. I copy and pasted my code in exactly as it I typed it. Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: @AdamZerner Like I said, you should do as I suggest in my last edit: `@college.majors.split('|').map{ |element| result = element.split(': '); [result[0], result[1].to_i] }.unshift(['Major', 'Percentage']).to_s.html_safe`

Answer (score 0):

[split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-split) once on the pipe and then again on the space.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'json'

majors.split('|').collect {|major| major.gsub('%', '').split(':').collect(&:strip) }.unshift(['Major', 'Percentage']).to_json
```

You could do some other tricks like splitting on '%|' and ': ' to avoid the gsub and strip, but to me that seems like it could be kind of brittle. A slight change in the formatting would break it.